# Unable to remove specific files from Maven build

Tags: maven, properties-file

I am currently working over Maven build. I want to remove specific file from my Maven build. I am currently trying with below code:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <webResources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <!-- override the destination directory for this resource -->
                <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>
                <!-- enable filtering -->
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>*.pem</include>
                    <include>*.pfx</include>
                    <include>META-INF/jpa-persistence.xml</include>
                    <include>META-INF/spring-persistence.xml</include>
                    <include>com/abc/config/build-config-${propertyenv}.properties</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>%regex[(?!.*${propertyenv}/)*]</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I have defined `propertyenv` as property value in my POM:

```
<properties>
    <propertyenv>abc</propertyenv>
</properties>
```

I only want `abc.properties` file from `com/abc/config` folder. But after build all `.properties` files are present. Kindly help.

Comment: i think what you are searching for is http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

Comment: @Abhishek How are Build Profiles supposed to help here? With profiles you activate/ovrerride settings with the values declared in it. How does this help if the settings themselves already do not do what is tried to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `packagingExcludes` or `packagingIncludes` Parameters to include or exclude files from the final war

Example:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.6</version>
          ....
    <configuration>
          ....
                <packagingExcludes>
                    WEB-INF/lib/pax-logging-*.jar, WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-*-2.2.7.jar 
                </packagingExcludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```